# CSS: Set Form Field Image Dimensions Regardless of Actual Image Size

Tags: css, forms

I would like form field images to have a set dimension regardless of the actual image size. So we want all form field images to be 25px by 25px, even if the actual image file is 35x by 35x. Current CSS is below, but if the url points to an image larger than the form field, it no worky. Newbie question for sure, but might be helpful for all future beginners as well.

```
      #namefieldicon {
      background: white url(example.com/images/nameicon.gif) left 
      no-repeat;

      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a snapshot check the link below

```
<div>
  <div class="bgimg"></div>
  <div class="bgimg"></div>
  <div class="bgimg"></div>
  <div class="bgimg"></div>
  <div class="bgimg"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.bgimg {
    background: white url(https://placehold.it/100/100) left no-repeat;
    background-size: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Is this what you mean?
https://jsbin.com/tavulac/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Thanks - very helpful. Creating a div class first.

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to mark it as a right answer 

Comment: I like the answer, but I was looking for a pure CSS solution.

Comment: and It's a pure CSS solution. you can use this CSS on most the elements on your page.
you don't have to use div. If you mean that you want to make it without using  HTML so it's impossible